# How to handle click event on same location marker

Tags: android, mapbox-android

I am using marker view in order to display marker.

My code:

```
View customView = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.dialog_obstacle_with_markers, null);
    customView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT));

    ImageView iv_marker = customView.findViewById(R.id.iv_marker);
    iv_marker.setTag(reportItemArrayList.get(i).getReportId());
    ImageView iv_marker_white = customView.findViewById(R.id.iv_marker_white);
    FrameLayout fl_category = customView.findViewById(R.id.fl_category);
    ImageView iv_obstacle = customView.findViewById(R.id.iv_obstacle);
    TextView tv_obstacle = customView.findViewById(R.id.tv_obstacle);
    int[] rgbValue = Utils.getRGBFromHex(reportItemArrayList.get(i).getColor());
    iv_marker.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(rgbValue[0], rgbValue[1], rgbValue[2]));

    Glide.with(activity)
            .load(reportItemArrayList.get(i).getFilename())
            .apply(new RequestOptions()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_obstacle_place_holder)
                    .error(R.mipmap.ic_obstacle_place_holder))
            .into(iv_obstacle);

    tv_obstacle.setText(reportItemArrayList.get(i).getCategoryName());

    MarkerView markerView = new MarkerView(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(reportItemArrayList.get(i).getLat()), Double.parseDouble(reportItemArrayList.get(i).getLng())), customView);
    markerViewManager.addMarker(markerView);
```

Here I have multiple same location markers available and I am able to see only first location marker and other marker are behind first marker due to same location.

Now I want to handle click event of other marker behind first marker.

Currently I am getting only first location marker click due to same location.

But I want all click events behind first marker.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

you can not handle the click event of same location markers like this.
the markers should have different locations to handle them.